# How can I stop GDM on Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop in order to install NVIDIA Driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lightdm, gdm, 18.04

In the case of Ubuntu 16.04. I can download the NVIDIA driver run file and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+F1 and then do the below

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.48.run
```

I follow on screen instructions to install and reboot and everything works.

Now I am trying to do the same thing on Ubuntu 18.04. I read that Ubuntu 18.04 switched to gdm so I tried

```
sudo service gdm stop
sudo gdm stop
```

None of them worked, after some searching I realized it could be gdm3 instead but I tried

```
sudo service gdm3 stop
sudo gdm3 stop
```

Still none of them worked, and of course `sudo service lightdm stop` doesn't work. When I tried to install the driver it kept telling me the x-server is still on so can't start the installation process.

What is the right way to stop gdm in Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 9):

Ubuntu has been using systemd for a while now.  This worked for me.

```
sudo systemctl stop gdm3
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I am using 18.10. Any hint on why?

Answer (score 1):

Dropping to run-level 3 and then installing the driver worked for me. You can change run-level using: `sudo telinit 3`.

Comment: Did this work for you on Ubuntu 18.04? The concept of run level [is a little redundant with `systemd` as init](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394238/165104). Instead one would theoretically run something like `systemctl isolate multi-user.target`.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04. I haven't tried the `systemctl` command that you mentioned.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.10. The `systemctl` command did not work. But I re-launched gdm3 with `systemctl`.

Answer (score 0):

You should better install the driver using: `sudo apt install nvidia-graphics-drivers-384`

Make sure that you updated your local repositories by using `sudo apt-get update`

Hope it works

Comment: I had bad experiences using apt to install nvidia drivers and would rather avoid it if possible.

Comment: Then try to kill xorg using `killall xorg` switch to TTY2 with CTRL + ALT + F2 and after that try to kill gdm.Hope it works

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. I ended up booting into recovery mode and drop to root shell to install NVIDIA driver. Not the best way but I hope someone can come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu on wayland, just try this:

```
sudo killall gdm-wayland-session
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and was able to update my driver by following these steps -

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> don't work in ubuntu 18.04)
2. `killall gdm`
3. Find the id of Xorg process and `kill -9 <process Id>`
4. run `sudo ./NVIDIA*.run`
5. `sudo systemctl start gdm3`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu 20.04 run this:

```
sudo systemctl stop gdm3
sudo systemctl stop lightdm
```

You can then start them again by running

```
sudo systemctl stop gdm3
sudo systemctl stop lightdm
```

If you have an RTX 3050, I'd recommend using lightdm

GLHF with these nvidia drivers man :')

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't have `lightdm`.

Comment: Then what am I using?
```
systemctl status display-manager.service
```


● lightdm.service - Light Display Manager

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu 20.04, then you are using GDM, unless you've changed it. They don't work at the same time.

Comment: It actually uses gdm3....
And yes, I had to change it since nvidia drivers and gdm3 don't play well together
I changed my display manager from gdm3 to lightdm to fix that issue :P